# Difference between getPort methods in javax.xml.ws.Service class

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, jax-ws

Scenario : 
In my WSDL I am having one PortType, which are getting used by a service through three different bindings; (just like Axis 2 generated wsdl)

There are overloaded methods of getPort in javax.xml.ws.Service class, [public  T getPort(Class  SEI)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/Service.html#getPort(java.lang.Class)) and [public  T getPort(QName portName, Class SEI)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/Service.html#getPort(javax.xml.namespace.QName,%20java.lang.Class)). Now, if I use the first one without mentioning the portName then which binding, endpoint address will it use? Basically what is the difference between the different overloaded getPort methods in Service class?

At the runtime I am having only the portType (SEI) name.

Excerpt from my WSDL :

```
 <wsdl:service name="HelloWorldService">
    <wsdl:port name="HelloWorldServiceHttpSoap11Endpoint" binding="ns:HelloWorldServiceSoap11Binding">
        <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/HelloWorldService.HelloWorldServiceHttpSoap11Endpoint/" />   
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="HelloWorldServiceHttpSoap12Endpoint" binding="ns:HelloWorldServiceSoap12Binding">
        <soap12:address location="http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/HelloWorldService.HelloWorldServiceHttpSoap12Endpoint/" /> 
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="HelloWorldServiceHttpEndpoint" binding="ns:HelloWorldServiceHttpBinding">
        <http:address location="http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/HelloWorldService.HelloWorldServiceHttpEndpoint/" /> 
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
```

Comment: [Ref](http://java.boot.by/ocewsd6-guide/ch06.html)

Comment: I don't think this link answers my question

Comment: Any idea how to get ports for a perticular portType (i.e. SEI).